# Do I need another JQuery plugin for Draggable to work?

Tags: jquery

I am doing some self-learning about JQuery.
Here is the code for my very simple HTML form:

```
    <html>
         <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            </head>
            <body>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#replybox").draggable();
                });
            </script>
            <div id="replybox">
            <form>
            <table border="2">       
            <tr>
            <td align="center">
<textarea name="data[Test][quote]" id="data[Test][quote]" rows="18"></textarea>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </form>
            </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

The DIV table just could not be draggable,
I am not sure what's wrong in the code.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can we consider changing the title of this question to something a little more useful... maybe:
Do I need another JQuery plugin for Draggable to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it looks like you're trying to use the jQueryUI framework. .draggable() is not natively jQuery --- the jQueryUI (plugin) adds that functionality in. [jQueryUI Home](http://jqueryui.com/)

Alternatively, you can also link directly to the jQueryUI instance in GoogleAPIs.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
```

But personally, I prefer to build my own download package from their home page, especially if all you need is .draggable().

Answer (score 3):

Draggable is part of the jquery UI which is not directly part of jQuery.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Comment: Seems some ppl have beat me to the punch.

Comment: I'll vote you up.  Not fair to not share the credit, especially with another jQuery geek!

Answer (score 2):

You just need the jQuery UI plugin.  See here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/